# Does enabling use of a dedicated GPU speed up Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, gpu

I have both an integrated GPU on the CPU as well a discrete NVIDIA GPU.  Would it be beneficial to enable it for some applications like Google Chrome even if they aren't doing 3D?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can help immensely.  I went into settings on Windows -> Graphics Settings and turned on use of the discrete GPU for Google Chrome and it made a MASSIVE performance difference for me despite nothing being 3D in any of the tabs.

I discovered this fortuitiously when I enabled it because I was trying a 3D site, and then I noticed all my slowness when only 2D tabs were open had gone away.  I also enabled it in the NVIDIA control panel (right click on the desktop to find it).

Passing along in case this helps anyone.  I'm on a quad core Xeon E3-1535M v6 @ 3.10Ghz, so while it's far from the best that's out there, it's also not too shabby and I was surprised to see such a huge difference.

Comment: This largely depends on which GPU is being used. For example, I have observed on the Nvidia MX110/120/130, etc., the GPU usage spikes up as hell and produces a lot of heat (yet it wasn't able to play a 4K video without stuttering), when Intel UHD graphics can easily play videos with very little heat (even 4K plays smoothly without stuttering). Yet, the only reason I use the Nvidia GPU for Chrome is its dedicated video memory - helps save some RAM that is otherwise borrowed by the Intel GPU.